# Rails / PHP : How to serialize an sql data row?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, serialization

What I want to do is build an application where user's profile is made out of several surveys. But this is not the main purpose of my work (although compulsory) so I want to achieve this the quickest way.

I found a wonderful solution with no equivalent to take surveys thanks to the limesurvey opensource php app.

Basically, I have anonymous users taking, let says 5 different big enough, surveys from a php application (limesurvey) that stores results into a mysql database.
This application can export those results into a csv file.

I'd like to build a rails app to handle private users and each of them would have the surveys attached to their profile each time they answer one.

After a quick search, I found that serializing would be a good option.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :collection, Array (ahum ??)
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many surveys
end
```

It seems that I have two options then:

1. Use the limesurvey export function to csv and then use fastercsv builtin'rails function to import this file as an openstruct survey object through the rails user manager(this would be quite simple I think :)
2. Use rails to query limesurvey mysql database to get the datarow with correct `survey_id` and `user_id`. And transform this datarow into a serialized object (into an openstruct ???).

Second solution appear to be better (and I have a couple of days to do it) but how to achieve this ? thanks in advance hoping I am clear enough !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way is to us JSON.

1-line encoding, 1-line decoding.

Comment: Alright I'm following you, let says I add to limesurvey an sql export to json then I can call an ajax rest service to rails to add this as an object ? I have to think about it help me please !

Comment: ...I see two problems, first limesurvey runs on a separate database and second it must be survey-content agnostic !